# Обработка oninput нескольких полей. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Привет всем.

Имею форму с тремя текстовым полями. Необходимо при изменении значений одной формы считать по разным формулам значения других. Расчеты необходимо делать после ввода каждого символа - хочу использовать oninput.

Как мне отловить событие изменения oninput каждого текстового поля по отдельности? На данный момент я разобрался как отловить событие формы, но мне нужно знать какое именно текстовое поле было изменено

```
calc.oninput = function () {
var lench = Number(document.getElementsByName('lench')[0].value);
var widtch = Number(document.getElementsByName('widtch')[0].value);
};
```

http://codepen.io/Korsic/pen/qNJqjA?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```js
 var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input');

 for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
   inp[i].addEventListener('keyup', myfunc);
 }

 function myfunc() {

      var lench = +document.getElementsByName('lench')[0].value;
   document.getElementById('len').innerHTML = lench;

   var width = +document.getElementsByName('width')[0].value;
   document.getElementById('wid').innerHTML = width;

 }
```

```html
<form name="calc">
  <input type="text" name="lench">
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="width">
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="count">
  <br />
</form>

Lench:
<div id="len"></div>
Width:
<div id="wid"></div>
```